# Modifying ActiveRecord Validations with mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an ActiveRecord mixin (I think you can call it that?) which adds various default scopes and callbacks to those models for the purpose of scoping multi-tenant queries.

What I'd also like to be able to do is modify the existing uniqueness validations on that model to include a scope. I found I can see all the validations using `Model.validators`, so I naturally tried to modify the scope option like so:

```
Model.validators
  .select{|v| v.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator)}
  .map{|v| v.options[:scope] = :client_id }
```

.. however this results in the error `RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Hash`, for the `options` hash. Anybody know how I can go about this? I understand it will probably involve some pretty hacky code.

If editing it isn't possible maybe I can override it or catch it or something?

Edit - I've found [this](http://casperfabricius.com/site/2008/12/06/removing-rails-validations-with-metaprogramming/), which is almost exactly what I'm trying to do but it won't work in Rails 3.2, I think they've completely changed how validations are stored? Can anyone help me/give me pointers on how to get this working in Rails 3?

Comment: there is surely a reason, why that hash is frozen, but if the `#options=#` setter is accessible, you can just dup the hash. or merge and overwrite (`options = options.merge(...)`)

Comment: oh, and that `map` makes no sense, it returns an array `[:client_id, :client_id, ...]` replace it by an `each`

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'options=' for #<ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator:0x007f9b0531ad88>` :(

Comment: then i would try to remove that validator and "recreate" it

Comment: I can't seem to mutate that array at all. Updated my question with a handy link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally cracked it. The key was `_validate_callbacks`:

```
def scope_validators(foreign_key)
  new_callback_chain = self._validate_callbacks.reject do |callback|
    callback.raw_filter.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator)
  end
  deleted = self._validate_callbacks - new_callback_chain
  (self._validate_callbacks.clear << new_callback_chain).flatten!
  deleted.each do |c|
    v = c.raw_filter
    v.attributes.each do |a|
      validates_uniqueness_of *v.attributes, v.options.merge(scope: foreign_key)
    end
  end
end
```

Works like a treat mixed in to models.